# Truth Table - Assistance

Tags: java, truthtable

I have a question for an assignment. The questions is basically the following:
There are 2 integer variables say A and B. Both these integers contain data.
Using a truth table, which, if any, of the following IF statement tests is equivalent to:

```
if (!(A == 60 && B == 40))   

 -   if (A != 60 || B != 40)
 -  if (A == 60 && (!(B == 40)))
```

How would i tackle this please. Anything advice would be appreciated. I think that I have to create a table with three columns - one called A, another B, and the third column called RESULT (YES OR NO).

The statement:  `if (!(A == 60 && B == 40))`    - I am not to sure how to read the part `if (!`.  In other words, the part `A == 60 && B == 40` is telling me essentially that A must equal 60 AND AT THE SAME TIME B must equal 40.  Following that I am confused.  Any help/advise please would be appreciated.

Thanks
Chris

Comment: [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)

Comment: if (NOT (Jane can swim AND bernd is 15 years old)) - can you deduce that?

Comment: Thanks heaps - ThisClark. And thank you for the link. Hope you gave  a great weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with Java per se. Yes, you can solve by writing the truth tables. The `!` means *logical negation* or *not* or you may even think of it as *opposite*. Personally, I find it helpful to establish all the parts of a particular truth table.

```
   a    |   b    |    !b     |       a & b       |      a & !b        |      !(a & b)
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 A = 60 | B = 40 | !(B = 40) | (A = 60 & B = 40) | A = 60 & !(B = 40) | !(A = 60 & B = 40)
   T    |   T    |     F     |         T         |        F           |          F
   T    |   F    |     T     |         F         |        T           |          T
   F    |   T    |     F     |         F         |        F           |          T
   F    |   F    |     T     |         F         |        F           |          T
```

You should note your particular example is subject to one of [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).

[image]

```
P is A = 60  
Q is B = 40  
¬ is !  
∧ is &&   
∨ is ||
```

so...

`!(A && B)` is really the same as `!A || !B`

The truth table tells you the rest you need to know to solve that problem.

Comment: Thanks ThisClark. Too good buddy. You explained it brilliantly. Thank you so much.  Chris

Comment: You're welcome. If you mark this as the accepted answer (click the checkmark), you'll earn your first rep points and it'll save it on your profile for future reference if you ever need.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code that I create help you to get an idea, this is a simple code to display the Truth Table using binary (0s and 1s) numbers instead of Boolean (TRUE, FALSE)

```
/**
 * Truth table for the logical operators. Using
 * zeros and ones.
 * 
 * @ Samuel Mayol
 */

public class LogicalOpTable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean p, q; 
        byte p1, q1, pAndQ, pOrQ, pXORq, notP, pq;

        System.out.println("Using 0s and 1s for the Truth Table:");
        System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOT"); // using tabs \t

        pq =1;

        switch (pq) { // without break it will execute the whole swich case statements
            case 1 : 
                p = true; q = true;
                p1=(byte) (p?1:0); // The ? : operator in Java
                q1=(byte) (q?1:0); // Short form for Java If statement
                pAndQ=(byte) ((p&q)?1:0); 
                pOrQ=(byte) ((p|q)?1:0);
                pXORq=(byte) ((p^q)?1:0);
                notP= (byte) ((!p)?1:0);

                System.out.print(p1 + "\t" + q1 + "\t");
                System.out.print(pAndQ + "\t" + pOrQ + "\t");
                System.out.println(pXORq + "\t" + notP);
            case 2: 
                p = true; q = false;
                p1=(byte) (p?1:0); // The ? : operator in Java
                q1=(byte) (q?1:0); // Short form for Java If statement
                pAndQ=(byte) ((p&q)?1:0); 
                pOrQ=(byte) ((p|q)?1:0);
                pXORq=(byte) ((p^q)?1:0);
                notP= (byte) ((!p)?1:0);

                System.out.print(p1 + "\t" + q1 + "\t");
                System.out.print(pAndQ + "\t" + pOrQ + "\t");
                System.out.println(pXORq + "\t" + notP);
            case 3: 
                p = false; q = true;
                p1=(byte) (p?1:0); // The ? : operator in Java
                q1=(byte) (q?1:0); // Short form for Java If statement
                pAndQ=(byte) ((p&q)?1:0); 
                pOrQ=(byte) ((p|q)?1:0);
                pXORq=(byte) ((p^q)?1:0);
                notP= (byte) ((!p)?1:0);

                System.out.print(p1 + "\t" + q1 + "\t");
                System.out.print(pAndQ + "\t" + pOrQ + "\t");
                System.out.println(pXORq + "\t" + notP);
            case 4: 
                p = false; q = false;
                p1=(byte) (p?1:0); // The ? : operator in Java
                q1=(byte) (q?1:0); // Short form for Java If statement
                pAndQ=(byte) ((p&q)?1:0); 
                pOrQ=(byte) ((p|q)?1:0);
                pXORq=(byte) ((p^q)?1:0);
                notP= (byte) ((!p)?1:0);

                System.out.print(p1 + "\t" + q1 + "\t");
                System.out.print(pAndQ + "\t" + pOrQ + "\t");
                System.out.println(pXORq + "\t" + notP);
        }
    }
}
```

The result after running this code is:

```
Using 0s and 1s for the Truth Table:
P   Q   AND OR  XOR NOT
1   1   1   1   0   0
1   0   0   1   1   0
0   1   0   1   1   1
0   0   0   0   0   1
```